# How can I make an attachment page for pdf uploads?

Tags: attachments, pdf

I have an attachment page for post images, so that when I click on the thumbnail (on the front end) it takes the user to the attachment page for that image, how would I do the same for pdf files, so that when I click on the direct link to the pdf on the front end to redirects to the pdf attachment page?

```
<?php if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $post->id ) ) : $att_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post->id, "full"); ?>
    <center>
    <p class="full-attachment">
        <?php /* <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($post->id); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="attachment"> */ ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $att_image[0];?>" width="<?php echo $att_image[1];?>" height="<?php echo $att_image[2];?>"  class="attachment-full" alt="<?php $post->post_title; ?>" />
        <?php /* </a> */ ?>
    </p>
    </center>
<?php else : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID) ?>" title="<?php echo wp_specialchars( get_the_title($post->ID), 1 ) ?>" rel="attachment">
        <?php echo basename($post->guid) ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is my theme file's single.php

```
<?php $file= get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'teacher-resume-upload' );
 if ( $file) { foreach ( $file as $attachment_id ) { $full_size = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ); printf( '<a href="%s">download</a>', $full_size); } } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pdf.php` or a number of other specially-named template files [as described birgire's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/253291/8559) to show an attachment page specifically for PDFs, or use a generic `attachment.php` page that includes conditional statements for the type of attachment (like the code in your question does).

### Potential Conflict with Yoast SEO Plugin

Note that attachment template pages may not work if you have the Yoast SEO plugin installed. The default setting under **Yoast SEO › Search Appearance › Media** is to 'Redirect attachment URLs to the attachment itself,' which will override any attachment page template and directly link to the PDF, image file, or whatever you've uploaded.

### How to Use Attachment Page Only for PDFs and Redirect Other Attachment Types Directly to their Files

Bonus: If you *only* want to show PDF attachment pages and redirect everything else to the attachment file, here's some code to do that. (You'd put this in your `functions.php` file.)

```php
/**
 * Redirect media attachment URLs to the attachment itself *unless* it's a PDF.
 * See details: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/253226/
 */
add_action(
  'template_redirect',
  function() {
    // Exit if this is not an attachment page.
    if ( ! is_attachment() ) {
      return;
    }

    // Exit (do nothing; do not redirect; use
    // the pdf.php attachment template page) 
    // if this is a PDF attachment page.
    if ( false !== stripos( get_post_mime_type(), 'pdf' ) ) {
      return;
    }

    // Redirect all other attachment pages to
    // their file. Use code '301' to indicate
    // this is a permanent redirect.
    if ( wp_get_attachment_url() ) {
      wp_safe_redirect( wp_get_attachment_url(), '301' );
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [`get_attachment_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attachment_template/) we can see how the attachment's  *template hierarchy* is constructed.

Let's check out some examples:

- For a *pdf* file, with the `applicaton/pdf` mime type it's:

  ```
  - application-pdf.php
  - pdf.php
  - application.php
  - attachment.php
  ```
- For a *jpeg* image with the `image/jpeg` mime type it's:

  ```
  - image-jpeg.php
  - jpeg.php
  - image.php
  - attachment.php
  ```
- For a *png* image with the `image/png` mime type it's:

  ```
  - image-png.php
  - png.php
  - image.php
  - attachment.php
  ```
- For an *mp3* audio file with the `audio/mpeg` mime type it's:

  ```
  - audio-mpeg.php
  - mpeg.php
  - audio.php
  - attachment.php
  ```

If none of these files exists in the current theme directory, then the fallbacks are (in order):

```
- {custom post template}.php
- single-attachment-{slug}.php
- single-attachment.php
- single.php
- singular.php
- index.php
```

I added the `{custom post template}.php` here, because we can add a postmeta row for the `_wp_page_template` key for a given attachment, with the template filename as a meta value.

If we check out the Codex on [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#attachment), then it seems to be missing some fallback options.

Then if we want to modify the *embed template* for attachments, then we can e.g. use `embed-attachment.php` or `embed.php`

Comment: Great thanks for that, I'll try to copy and modify my image attachment template.

Comment: you're welcome, hope it worked for you @Pete

Comment: Nope it didn't unfortunately

Comment: strange, I just created the pdf.php file under the TwentySixteen theme and it displays as my PDF attachment page @Pete

Comment: Not strange, I'm sure you're right. I'm just not smart enough to work out how to adapt my attachment.php file (see above).

Comment: I just created the `pdf.php` file in my current theme directory, containing only the string "Hello from PDF", just to see if it overrides the pdf attachment's page. What happens if you try that? @Pete

Comment: It downloads the pdf file... i've added the relevant single .php code that has the pdf links.

Comment: No not the file itself. When I find my pdf files in the media library and hover over it with the mouse, I can see the **view** link and that link takes me to the attachment's page. @Pete

Comment: My pdf's I mean

Comment: sorry, I guess I'm just misunderstanding your setup and what the goal is ;-) @Pete

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php if ( get_post_mime_type($post->ID) == 'application/pdf' ) : ?>
    <object data="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID); ?>" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="1000px"><a href="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID); ?>">Download the PDF here.</a></object>
<?php endif; ?>
```

`get_post_mime_type()` tells your what the type of your attachment is - kinda like the `wp_attachment_is_image($post->ID)`. If it matches PDF then the code is being executed.

When you run this outside of the `attachment.php` template file you should wrap the code in `<?php if is_attachment(): ?> <?php endif; ?>`.

Comment: It doesn't show any link in my single.php

Comment: In another comment you are mentioning that you want to adapt it to your attachment.php. This code should go in attachment.php.

Comment: Where is relation to my above example?

Comment: So many google pages before I found this thanks!